# Crystal lang how to get binary file from http

Tags: http, binary, crystal-lang

In Ruby:

```
require 'open-uri'
download = open('http://example.com/download.pdf')
IO.copy_stream(download, '~/my_file.pdf')
```

How to do the same in Crystal?

Comment: So much less effort is not a good start for this community.

Comment: I spent enough time googling without result

Comment: https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.21.0/HTTP/WebSocket/Protocol/StreamIO.html gives 404

Answer (score 10):

We can do the following:

```
require "http/client"

HTTP::Client.get("http://example.org") do |response|
  File.write("example.com.html", response.body_io)
end
```

This writes just the response without any HTTP headers to the file. `File.write` is also smart enough to not download the entire file into memory first, but to write to the file as it reads chunks from the given `IO`.

Comment: Thanks John, it's working to, but without http-headers

Answer (score 1):

I found something that works:

```
require "http/request"
require "file"
res = HTTP::Client.get "https://ya.ru"
fl=File.open("ya.html","wb")
res.to_io(fl)
fl.close
```

Comment: Of course you should prefer the block form of `File.open`.