# A Library For Web Scraping In Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

I have been using Scrapy with Python for web scraping, is there anything similar for Crytal? 
I tried to make a Google search but I found nothing.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's any in the `awesome-crystal` list [here](https://github.com/veelenga/awesome-crystal). You can ask for one on the `crystal-libraries-needed` repository [here](https://github.com/crystal-community/crystal-libraries-needed). I personally have no idea how hard it is to make a web scraping library, so I'm not sure how achieveable it is to just make the library itself. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: As an aside, this type of question generally isn't accepted on SO where you ask for a certain library that achieves a purpose, since it attracts opinionated answers rather than subjective answers. You could ask the same question in the project's Gitter chat [here](https://gitter.im/crystal-lang/crystal).

Comment: You could download the files yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580251/crystal-lang-how-to-get-binary-file-from-http but that's not a scraping library per se.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This site](https://crystalshards.xyz/) is the best place to look for shards, IMHO.
About scrapping or parsing html I started playing with [Myhtml](https://github.com/kostya/myhtml) but also found [Crystagiri](https://github.com/madeindjs/Crystagiri) and [June](https://github.com/codenoid/June)